# How to write answer from server to client (Java, HTML)

Tags: java, http, server

I am writing my first and very simple Java Server.

In the method sendAnswer I have 2 cases: 1 - if URL has "/s" I want user to see in Browser message Page and then append IP address of user. So, my first question, how could I append thisIp.getHostAddress() to message?

The second case - not found - I want user to see in Browser Page Not Found message - it works! But not for first case - the browser shows nothing and I also get an error **net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH**. Could you please tell me, where is a mistake?

```
    public void sendAnswer() throws IOException {
        try {
          if(request.getUri().equals("/s")) {
            InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("IP:"+thisIp.getHostAddress());
            String msg  = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n" +
                    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                    "Content-Length: 23\r\n" +
                    "\r\n" +
                    "<h1>Page</h1>";
            output.write(msg.getBytes());
            output.flush();

          }
          else {
            //  not found
            String errorMessage = "HTTP/1.1 404 Page Not Found\r\n" +
              "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
              "Content-Length: 23\r\n" +
              "\r\n" +
              "<h1>Page Not Found</h1>";
            output.write(errorMessage.getBytes());
            output.flush();

          }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          // thrown if cannot instantiate a File object
          System.out.println(e.toString() );
        }
      }
```

Comment: `<h1>Page</h1>` length seem about 10, not 23

Comment: @JacekCz did you mean 13?

Comment: @JacekCz Thanks! It helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JacekCz (*mistakenly*) pointed out, you wrongly set the content length:

```
net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

means that there's an error in the content length

```
String msg  = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
    "Content-Length: 23\r\n" +
     "\r\n" +
     "<h1>Page</h1>";
```

is wrong because your message, `<h1>Page</h1>`, has a length of **13**, not 23 (and not 10 either, like @JacekCz commented).

Often, the answer to our questions is in the error code itself. Make sure to read the error message first before asking :)